# Quasiquotes escaping

Tags: haskell, parsec, megaparsec, quasiquotes

I would like to add my new language to Haskell using the Quasiquotes, but the language itself uses `|]` as a keyword.

Is there some way, how to:

a) Escape `|]`, so it is passed to my language

b) Let the parser of my language decide, when the quasiquotation ends itself

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**: slightly modify the embedded language.

The [*User's Guide* on *QuasiQuoters*](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/template_haskell.html#template-haskell-quasi-quotation) explains that no escaping can done for the `|]`:

> The quoted `⟨string⟩` finishes at the **first occurrence of the two-character sequence `"|]"`**. Absolutely **no escaping is performed**. If you want to embed that character sequence in the string, you must invent your own escape convention (such as, say, using the string `"|~]"` instead), and make your quoter function interpret `"|~]"` as `"|]"`.

Your parser can not decide when the quasiquoters ends, because the substring is passed to the quasiquoter that started after the `[quasiquoter|…` part and before the `…|]` part.

You thus should slightly alter your language and thus for example work with a pre-processor that translate `|~]` (which is not considered the end of the quasiquoted string) to `|]` instead.